# What are the number of verses in Bhagavata if we count one verse as 32 syllable long?

Tags: bhagavata-purana

Bhagavata purana's length according to the Purana itself is 18000 verses long.

However, what constitutes as a verse is not defined.

There are varying lengths of verses counted as one verse.

Type 1:(long)

First two verses of Bhagavatam look like:

> SB 1.1.1
>
> janmady asya yato ’nvayad itaratas carthesv abhijñah svarat  tene
>   brahma hrda ya adi-kavaye muhyanti yat surayah tejo-vari-mrdam yatha
>   vinimayo yatra tri-sargo ’mrsa  dhamna svena sada nirasta-kuhakam
>   satyam param dhimahi
>
> SB 1.1.2
>
> dharmah projjhita-kaitavo ’tra paramo nirmatsaranam satam  vedyam
>   vastavam atra vastu sivadam tapa-trayonmulanam srimad-bhagavate
>   maha-muni-krte kim va parair isvarah  sadyo hrdy avarudhyate ’tra
>   krtibhih susrusubhis tat-ksanat

Type 2:(short)

> SB 1.1.9 tatra tatrañjasayusman  bhavata yad viniscitam pumsam
>   ekantatah sreyas  tan nah samsitum arhasi
>
> SB 1.1.10 prayenalpayusah sabhya  kalav asmin yuge janah mandah
>   sumanda-matayo  manda-bhagya hy upadrutah

Type 3:(prose)

> SB 5.9.9-10 sa ca prākṛtair dvipada-paśubhir
>   unmatta-jaḍa-badhira-mūkety abhibhāṣyamāṇo yadā tad-anurūpāṇi
>   prabhāṣate karmāṇi ca kāryamāṇaḥ parecchayā karoti viṣṭito vetanato vā
>   yācñayā yadṛcchayā vopasāditam alpaṁ bahu mṛṣṭaṁ kadannaṁ
>   vābhyavaharati paraṁ nendriya-prīti-nimittam.
>   nitya-nivṛtta-nimitta-sva-siddha-viśuddhānubhavānanda-svātma-lābhādhigamaḥ
>   sukha-duḥkhayor dvandva-nimittayor asambhāvita-dehābhimānaḥ.
>   śītoṣṇa-vāta-varṣeṣu vṛṣa ivānāvṛtāṅgaḥ pīnaḥ saṁhananāṅgaḥ
>   sthaṇḍila-saṁveśanānunmardanāmajjana-rajasā mahāmaṇir
>   ivānabhivyakta-brahma-varcasaḥ kupaṭāvṛta-kaṭir upavītenoru-maṣiṇā
>   dvijātir iti brahma-bandhur iti saṁjñayātaj-jñajanāvamato vicacāra.
>
> SB 5.14.1 sa hovāca sa eṣa dehātma-mānināṁ
>   sattvādi-guṇa-viśeṣa-vikalpita-kuśalāku-śala-samavahāra-vinirmita-vividha-dehāvalibhir
>   viyoga-saṁyogādy-anādi-saṁsārānubhavasya dvāra-bhūtena
>   ṣaḍ-indriya-vargeṇa tasmin durgādhvavad asugame ’dhvany āpatita
>   īśvarasya bhagavato viṣṇor vaśa-vartinyā māyayā jīva-loko ’yaṁ yathā
>   vaṇik-sārtho ’rtha-paraḥ sva-deha-niṣpādita-karmānubhavaḥ śmaśānavad
>   aśivatamāyāṁ saṁsārāṭavyāṁ gato nādyāpi viphala-bahu-pratiyogehas
>   tat-tāpopaśamanīṁ hari-guru-caraṇāravinda-madhukarānupadavīm
>   avarundhe.
>
> SB 5.14.2 yasyām u ha vā ete ṣaḍ-indriya-nāmānaḥ karmaṇā dasyava eva
>   te; tad yathā puruṣasya dhanaṁ yat kiñcid dharmaupayikaṁ
>   bahu-kṛcchrādhigataṁ sākṣāt parama-puruṣārādhana-lakṣaṇo yo ’sau
>   dharmas taṁ tu sāmparāya udāharanti; tad-dharmyaṁ dhanaṁ
>   darśana-sparśana-śravaṇāsvādanāvaghrāṇa-saṅkalpa-vyavasāya-gṛha-grāmyopabhogena
>   kunāthasyājitātmano yathā sārthasya vilum-panti.

There may be some other types of verses as well.

It is said that if we count the verses as per the length of type 2. We may get 18,000 verses.

How many verses in total do we get when we take 32 syllables as one verse?

Comment: A similar question is already present with an answer. So for time being I am closing your question as duplicate-

Comment: Also do check Bulk Of Bhagavata - https://archive.org/details/srimadbhagavatam015438mbp/page/n13